# C# 3.0: Need to return duplicates from a List<>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, iequalitycomparer

I have a List<> of objects in C# and I need a way to return those objects that are considered duplicates within the list.  I do not need the Distinct resultset, I need a list of those items that I will be deleting from my repository.

For the sake of this example, lets say I have a list of "Car" types and I need to know which of these cars are the same color as another in the list.  Here are the cars in the list and their color property:

```
Car1.Color = Red;

Car2.Color = Blue;

Car3.Color = Green;

Car4.Color = Red;

Car5.Color = Red;
```

For this example I need the result (IEnumerable<>, List<>, or whatever) to contain Car4 and Car5 because I want to delete these from my repository or db so that I only have one car per color in my repository.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I inadvertently coded this yesterday, when I was trying to write a "distinct by a projection". I included a ! when I shouldn't have, but this time it's just right:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DuplicatesBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        // Yield it if the key hasn't actually been added - i.e. it
        // was already in the set
        if (!seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then call it with:

```
var duplicates = cars.DuplicatesBy(car => car.Color);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer Jon. Helped me to optimize my ways of finding duplicates in a list.

Comment: Resharper tells me to refactor the foreach in your code with:
return source.Where(element => !seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));

Comment: @Koen: Ick - I dare say it would work, but I don't like the idea of including a side-effect in a predicate. (That would also change the timing of when the hashset was created, but that's a minor matter.)

Comment: One other thing: all elements with the same key but the first (in loop order) are returned (so if you have 3 duplicates, 2 elements are returned), wich may seem like odd behavior to me. Either return all duplicates or return only the key once...

Answer (score 17):

```
var duplicates = from car in cars
                 group car by car.Color into grouped
                 from car in grouped.Skip(1)
                 select car;
```

This groups the cars by color and then skips the first result from each group, returning the remainder from each group flattened into a single sequence.

If you have particular requirements about which one you want to keep, e.g. if the car has an `Id` property and you want to keep the car with the lowest `Id`, then you could add some ordering in there, e.g.

```
var duplicates = from car in cars
                 group car by car.Color into grouped
                 from car in grouped.OrderBy(c => c.Id).Skip(1)
                 select car;
```

Comment: +1 - I didn't think of the Skip(1) because the asker only wanted the duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a slightly different Linq solution that I think makes it more obvious what you're trying to do:

```
var s = from car in cars
    group car by car.Color into g
    where g.Count() == 1
    select g.First();
```

It's just grouping cars by color, tossing out all the groups that have more than one element, and then putting the rest into the returned IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerable<Car> GetDuplicateColors(List<Car> cars)
{
    return cars.Where(c => cars.Any(c2 => c2.Color == c.Color && cars.IndexOf(c2) < cars.IndexOf(c) ) );
}
```

It basically means "return cars where there's any car in the list with the same color and a smaller index".

Not sure of the performance, though.  I suspect an approach with a O(1) lookup for duplicates (like the dictionary/hashset method) can be faster for large sets.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new `Dictionary<Color, Car> foundColors` and a `List<Car> carsToDelete`

Then you iterate through your original list of cars like so:

```
foreach(Car c in listOfCars)
{
    if (foundColors.containsKey(c.Color))
    {
        carsToDelete.Add(c);
    }
    else
    {
        foundColors.Add(c.Color, c);
    }
}
```

Then you can delete every car that's in foundColors.

You could get a minor performance boost by putting your "delete record" logic in the `if` statement instead of creating a new list, but the way you worded the question suggested that you needed to collect them in a List.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually coding it, how about an algorithm something like this:

- iterate through your `List<T>` creating a `Dictionary<T, int>`
- iterate through your `Dictionary<T, int>` deleting entries where the `int` is >1

Anything left in the `Dictionary` has duplicates.  The second part where you actually delete is optional, of course.  You can just iterate through the `Dictionary` and look for the >1's to take action.

EDIT: OK, I bumped up Ryan's since he actually gave you code.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

My answer takes inspiration (in this order) from the followers respondents: Joe Coehoorn, Greg Beech and Jon Skeet.

I decided to provide a full example, with the assumption being (for real word efficiency) that you have a static list of car colors.  I believe the following code illustrates a complete solution to the problem in an elegant, although not necessarily hyper-efficient, manner.

```
#region SearchForNonDistinctMembersInAGenericListSample
public static string[] carColors = new[]{"Red", "Blue", "Green"}; 
public static string[] carStyles = new[]{"Compact", "Sedan", "SUV", "Mini-Van", "Jeep"}; 
public class Car
{
    public Car(){}
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Style { get; set; }
}
public static List<Car> SearchForNonDistinctMembersInAList()
{
    // pass in cars normally, but declare here for brevity
    var cars = new List<Car>(5) { new Car(){Color=carColors[0], Style=carStyles[0]}, 
                                      new Car(){Color=carColors[1],Style=carStyles[1]},
                                      new Car(){Color=carColors[0],Style=carStyles[2]}, 
                                      new Car(){Color=carColors[2],Style=carStyles[3]}, 
                                      new Car(){Color=carColors[0],Style=carStyles[4]}};
    List<Car> carDupes = new List<Car>();

    for (int i = 0; i < carColors.Length; i++)
    {
        Func<Car,bool> dupeMatcher = c => c.Color == carColors[i];

        int count = cars.Count<Car>(dupeMatcher);

        if (count > 1) // we have duplicates
        {
            foreach (Car dupe in cars.Where<Car>(dupeMatcher).Skip<Car>(1))
            {
                carDupes.Add(dupe);
            }
        }
    }
    return carDupes;
}
#endregion
```

I'm going to come back through here later and compare this solution to all three of its inspirations, just to contrast the styles.  It's rather interesting.

Answer (score 0):

public static IQueryable Duplicates(this IEnumerable source) where TSource : IComparable 
{

```
if (source == null)   
     throw new ArgumentNullException("source");   
 return source.Where(x => source.Count(y=>y.Equals(x)) > 1).AsQueryable<TSource>();
```

}